# why is my predicted LSTM model shifted left as well as the accuracy 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I have seen some other posts with shifted LSTM models being shifted however looking into them I didn't find a solution.Is something wrong with how im slicing the data in the Sequential_Input function? Does anyone have any suggestions? As well as that its odd that the accuracy is a constant zero rather then some kind of more random convergence to 1.

Below is the code and images from the model.

```
import pandas as pd
import utilities
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sklearn as sk
import pathlib
from ItemIdEnum import item
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
import seaborn as sns
from statsmodels.graphics.gofplots import qqplot
from scipy.stats import norm, uniform


def Sequential_Input_LSTM(df, input_sequence):
    df_np = df.to_numpy()
    X = []
    y = []
    
    for i in range(len(df_np) - input_sequence):
        row = [a for a in df_np[i:i + input_sequence]]
        X.append(row)
        label = df_np[i + input_sequence]
        y.append(label)
        
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

def createLSTM(itemName: str, data: pd.DataFrame, n_input: int, n_features: int, epochs: int, batch_size: int, save: bool, savePlot: bool) -> None:
    cwd = pathlib.Path().cwd()
    path = cwd.joinpath("LSTM_models/"+itemName)
    try:
        path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=False)
    except FileExistsError as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    
    early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'loss', patience = 5)
    data = utilities.convertFromZuluTime(data)
    data = utilities.removeOutliers(data)

    data = data.drop(columns=['range','universe_id','http_last_modified'])
    data['issued'] = pd.to_datetime(data['issued'],origin='unix',unit='D')
    date_time = pd.to_datetime(data['issued'])
    data.set_index('issued',inplace=True)
    plt.figure()
    data['price'].hist()
    plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_predata_standarize_hist.png')
    plt.figure()
    data['price'].plot(ylabel='Price')
    plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_predata_standarize_plot.png')
    xFeat = data
   
    sc =MinMaxScaler()
    X_ft = sc.fit_transform(xFeat.values)
    X_ft = pd.DataFrame(X_ft, index=xFeat.index, columns=xFeat.columns)
    plt.figure()
    data['price'].hist()
    plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_postdata_standarize_hist.png')
    plt.figure()
    data['price'].plot()
    plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_postdata_standarize_plot.png')
    n_input = n_input  

    df_min_model_data = X_ft['price']

    X, y = Sequential_Input_LSTM(df_min_model_data, n_input)
    trainSplit = 0.8
    splitIDX = int(np.floor(len(X)*trainSplit))
    dateIndex = date_time
    XTrain, xTest = X[:splitIDX], X[splitIDX:]
    yTrain, yTest = y[:splitIDX], y[splitIDX:]
    XTrainDates, xTestDates = dateIndex[:splitIDX], dateIndex[splitIDX+10:]


    n_features = n_features

    lstm = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((n_input,n_features)))
    lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
    lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
    lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50))
    lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
    lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    lstm.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(),tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
    lstm.summary()

    history = lstm.fit(XTrain,yTrain,epochs=epochs,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False,validation_data=(xTest,yTest), callbacks = [early_stop] )
    lstm.evaluate(xTest,yTest,verbose=0) # type: ignore
    if save == True:
        tf.keras.models.save_model(lstm, somePath")
    
    test_predictions1 = lstm.predict(xTest).flatten()

    X_test_list = []
    for i in range(len(xTest)):
        X_test_list.append(xTest[i][0])
    
    test_predictions_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X_test':list(X_test_list), 
                                    'LSTM Prediction':list(test_predictions1)})

    test_predictions_df1.plot(title=f'{itemName} LSTM Prediction vs Actual',ylabel='Price')
    plt.show()
    
    if savePlot == True:
        plt.figure()
        test_predictions_df1.plot(title=f'{itemName} LSTM Prediction vs Actual',ylabel='Price')
        plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_prediction_plot.png')

        print(history.history.keys())
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(history.history['loss'],label='loss')
        plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'],label='val_loss')
        plt.title('loss')
        plt.ylabel('loss')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend()
        plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_loss_plot.png')
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'],label='accuracy')
        plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'],label='val_accuracy')
        plt.title('accuracy')
        plt.ylabel('accuracy_values')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend()
        plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_accuracy_plot.png')
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(history.history['root_mean_squared_error'],label='root_mean_squared_error')
        plt.plot(history.history['val_root_mean_squared_error'],label='val_root_mean_squared_error')
        plt.title('root_mean_squared_error')
        plt.ylabel('root_mean_squared_values')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend()
        plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_root_mean_squared_error_plot.png')
```

[image: RMSE]
[image: Loss]
[image: Accuracy]
[image: Predicted vs Test]

Comment: You are doing regression, where accuracy makes no sense as it is a classification metric. Think about that.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy humm i guess that makes sense however i assumed it would compare it to the validation set in order to get the accuracy. Versus correctly classifying something.

Comment: How do you compare equality for continuous values? That is what regression means, opposite of discrete values in classification.

Comment: Humm fair point, i guess i don't quite understand how that works as well as i thought.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a forecasting problem. Because it's taking the data sequentially, the model responds to the impulsive spikes with a prediction, it's not learning to anticipate them. It looks like this was as close as your model got, and your plot is probably what your minimum loss looks like on this data.

Instead of accuracy, which in tensorflow/keras is a classification metric, you might try something like MSE, MAPE, etc, which would be a little closer to what I think you're looking for.

Comment: what would be some things i could do to help the model anticipate them?

Comment: Are they a fixed distance from each other? Are there features that seem to predict a spike? I'd look at whether you can predict the spikes using deltas and good old-fashioned linear regression, first. Once you have a sense of what features make a difference, then you'll be in a better place to try to use a powerful model like an LSTM.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you are solving a regression problem. So you are working with a continuous, noncategorical variable, so calculating accuracy loses its meaning.

You have already used mse as a metric, alternatively you can use mean_absolute_error.

Replace your following code with the one below.

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'],label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'],label='val_accuracy')
plt.title('accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy_values')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_accuracy_plot.png')
```

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_error'],label='mean_absolute_error')
plt.plot(history.history['val_mean_absolute_error'],label='val_mean_absolute_error')
plt.title('mean_absolute_error')
plt.ylabel('mean_absolute_value')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(f'{path/itemName}_mean_absolute_error_plot.png')
```

Comment: thanks however this was already answered in the comment section